# Hurst exponent calculation methodology

Tags: references, fractal

I am looking for the Hurst exponent calculation methodology. Please suggest online materials / methodology papers.

Comment: Linking related question (more specific though): http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46553/assumptions-for-hurst-exponent-calculation

Comment: You can find many implementations in Matlab in this link: http://prorum.com/index.php/2173/calcular-expoente-exponent-dependencia-dependence-temporais

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The calculation is covered on [the related wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurst_exponent).

R has several implementations for this:

1. The [fArma package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fArma) provides 10 different functions to estimate the Hurst exponent (see [LrdModelling](http://help.rmetrics.org/fArma/html/LrdModelling.html)).
2. The Rwave package has the [hurst.est() function](http://www.stat.ucl.ac.be/ISdidactique/Rhelp/library/Rwave/html/hurst.est.html).
3. The fractal package has the [hurstACVF() function](http://bm2.genes.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/R_current/library/fractal/man/hurstACVF.html).
4. The [dvfBm package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dvfBm/) is intended entirely for this purpose: "Hurst exponent estimation of a fractional Brownian motion by using discrete variations methods in presence of outliers and/or an additive noise".

The methods covered by fArma are taken from the ["Estimators for Long-Range Dependence: An Empirical Study"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.55.8251) (Taqqu, Teverovsky, Willinger 1995).

*Edit:* Just to add from the M. Tibbits comment below, you can find the [Hurst exponent](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9842) code for Matlab offered under a BSD license.  The description:

> This is an implementation of the Hurst
>   exponent calculation that is smaller,
>   simpler, and quicker than most others.
>   It does a dispersional analysis on the
>   data and then uses Matlab's polyfit to
>   estimate the Hurst exponent. It comes
>   with a test driver that you can
>   delete.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know any Matlab / Mathematica based packages?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not.  But R is fully open source so all the algorithms above will be very transparent if you want to re-implement.

Comment: and if you google for matlab hurst exponent you'll find several.

Comment: First result from google: [Hurst Exponential](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9842)

Answer (score 3):

[Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) has a built-in Hurst Exponent function.