# Assumptions for Hurst exponent calculation

Tags: time-series, assumptions, fractal

Are there any general assumptions for the calculation of the [Hurst exponent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurst_exponent)?

- Does the signal need to be stationary, for example?
- Does it depend on the method?
- What about the length of the time series, is longer better?

I am interested in using implementing it for the analysis of an EEG signal. I have read many articles but can't find answers for these questions.